# Resumable download setup across computers connected via the internet?

Tags: download, p2p

Like the question says, I want a solution to download **large** files across computers on the net, and I want to do it across multiple sessions so the download should be resumable. The host computer runs Windows, the computer doing the download could be Windows/Linux/Mac. I've tried Opera Unite, but that doesn't seem to support resumable downloads. I've also tried Sendoid without success.

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve uploading files to a server and then downloading it off the server.

Comment: torrent is the first thing that comes to my mind

Comment: Torrents mean being publicly addressable on the net. If everything else fails, I'll set up dynamic dns and retroshare, oneswarm or a torrent. But I'm hoping there are solutions that take the dynamic dns setup out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [DC++](http://dcplusplus.sourceforge.net/). I have always used it over a LAN but it does work over the internet and supports SSL and the downloads are resumable.